# Show that the set $\{e_j\}_{j=1}^\infty \cup \{e_j+e_{j+1}\}_{j=1}^\infty$ is a frame of $l^2$, and find the frame constants $A$ and $B$.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $e_j=(0,\dots,0,1,0,\dots)$ where "$1$" is the $j$-th component of the vector. Show that the set $\{e_j\}_{j=1}^\infty \cup \{e_j+e_{j+1}\}_{j=1}^\infty$ is a frame of $l^2$, and find the frame constants $A$ and $B$.

For your set to be a frame, you need
$$\alpha\,\|v\|^2\leq\sum_k|\langle e_k,v\rangle|^2\leq\beta\|v\|^2$$
for **every** vector $v$ and certain fixed constants $\alpha,\beta>0$.

How would I continue?

Comment: What is a "frame"? I've never heard that term.

Comment: I provided the definition above.

Comment: Every basis of a finite dimensional vector space forms a frame for that vector space. However I am stuck because I have an infinite dimensional vector space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence $e_1,e_2,e_3,\cdots$ is an orthonormal sequence. Similarly,
$$
   \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(e_1+e_2), \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(e_3+e_4),
            \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(e_5+e_6),\cdots.
$$
is an orthonormal sequence, just as is the sequence
$$
     \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(e_2+e_3),\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(e_4+e_5),\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(e_6+e_7),\cdots.
$$
For any orthonormal sequence $\{ u_{j} \}$, one has Bessel's inequality
$$
               \sum_{j}|(x,u_j)|^{2} \le \|x\|^{2}.
$$
Therefore,
$$
           \sum_{j}\left\{|(x,e_{j})|^{2}+|(x,e_{j}+e_{j+1})|^{2}\right\} \\
    =\sum_{j}|(x,e_{j})|^{2}+\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}2|(x,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(e_{2j-1}+e_{2j}))|^{2}+\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}2|(x,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(e_{2j}+e_{2j+1})|^{2} \\
          \le \|x\|^{2}+2\|x\|^{2}+2\|x\|^{2} = 5\|x\|^{2}.
$$
Because $\{ e_{j} \}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ is a complete orthonormal basis, then Parseval's equality gives $\sum_{j}|(x,e_{j})|^{2}=\|x\|^{2}$. So, as a crude estimate,
$$
      \|x\|^{2} \le \sum_{j}\left\{|(x,e_{j})|^{2}+|(x,e_{j}+e_{j+1})|^{2}\right\}.
$$
So these may not be the best constants, but they work: $\alpha=1$, $\beta=5$.